# Is there a way to hide/disable the list entries in oracle apex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, oracle-apex

In my oracle application page, i have a button that shows a list of actions that can be performed by the user ( the list is defined in Shared components > lists).
Now, based on some conditions i want to hide some of the actions, that are visible to the user( or disable it) . i have tried dynamic actions, but since this is not a standard "select" list, its not working.
please advise.

[image])

Thanks in advance. :)

Edit: I want to do it with dynamic action( page load will not happen)

Answer (score 0):

Every list entry has its **Conditions** section.

As you said - you already know which conditions have to be met for each user so that certain entry is (or is not) displayed. Therefore, use those conditions.

From my point of view, creating a **function** that returns Boolean is a good choice. If it accepts `:APP_USER` as a parameter, you can perform various checks and return `TRUE` if that particular user is supposed to see that entry or `FALSE` (so that it is hidden from them).

Comment: the conditions are not based on global item, but rather on page level item. also since the condition is based on page level item, meaning we are not relying on page load for it to be hidden

Comment: You can also use page level items in a condition on a shared component - doesn't need to be page items